# Number of times a prime divides a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $E_{p}(n)$ denote the number of times that $p$ divides $n$.

(a) show that if $n<p\leq 2n$ then $E_{p}({2n \choose n} )=1.$

(b) Show that if $\dfrac{2}{3}n<p\leq n$ then $E_{p}({2n \choose n}) =0$ unless $n=2$.

(c) Show that if $\sqrt{2n}<p\leq n$ then $E_{p}({2n\choose n})\leq 1$.

I'm not sure no who to show this I think I have to make use of that fact that $E_{p}(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor{\dfrac{n}{p^{k}}}\right \rfloor$  but I'm not sure on how to use this.

So for (a) the number I want is $E_{p}(2n!)-2E_{p}(n!)$.

Comment: For (a), notice that $p$ is a factor of $(2n)!$, but it is not a factor of $n!$.  So it does not cancel when you work out the binomial coefficient. Hence...

Comment: Hence it divides ${2n \choose n}$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Use similar ideas for (b) and (c).  In (b), how big is $3p$?  In (c), how big is $p^2$? Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember these exact statements being proved in Erdos's elementary proof of Bertrand's postulate, there is a proof on wikipedia if you're interested.

Comment: Sorry but I just can't get part (c). Well we have that $p2>2n$ in fact I played around with the inequality's and got $2n<p(p-1)+1$ so we have that $2n!$ has at most $p-1f$ actors that are dividable by p. And my current goal is to show that $n!$ has at least $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ factors that are dividable by p.Then this would show that $E_{p}({2n\choose n})\leq 1$.